# Send a interaction to a server only after user stops to interact with numeric input

Tags: react-native, react-native-component

I have a react native app. This app contains a personalised numeric component. I'm using this [solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-numeric-input). Every tick fires a onChange property. This onChange fires a function which send component value to a server. However, I wouldn't like to send every value generated in every interaction, only after user stops to interact with controls. Something like onMouseOut event.

How could I implement a component like this?

Code Example of actual [solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-numeric-input):

```
<NumericInput 
        value={this.state.value} 
        onChange={value => this.setState({value})} 
        onLimitReached={(isMax,msg) => console.log(isMax,msg)}
        totalWidth={240} 
        totalHeight={50} 
        iconSize={25}
        step={1.5}
        valueType='real'
        rounded 
        textColor='#B0228C' 
        iconStyle={{ color: 'white' }} 
        rightButtonBackgroundColor='#EA3788' 
        leftButtonBackgroundColor='#E56B70'/>
```

Thanks.